# Как зафиксировать только один блок, но чтобы он пролистывался?

Tags: html, css

Как это можно сделать? Например здесь http://circeya.ru/ это реализовано, в шапке.
Если делать фиксированную шапку, она просто остается на месте при любом скроле.

Comment: а если сделать z-index для шапки меньше, чем остальному контенту ?

Comment: @Александр,  Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @Александр,  Вы из Белгорода?

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае блок с изображением в шапке задаётся `position:fixed` при скроле страницы от 0 до 240 top блока изменяется вслед за скролом страницы. 
Z-index блока с изображением и блоков с текстом одинаков, но блоки с текстом находятся ниже по дереву и тем самым плавно перекрывается блок с изображением при скроле.

Answer (score 1):

Первому блоку section.main указано position: fixed; и высота height: 871px;
У второго за ним блока section.chance верхний отступ на эту же величину margin-top: 871px; z-index как уже сказали одинаковый. Вот и весь секрет

```
<style>
    header {        
        position: fixed;
        height: 100px;
    }
    .layout {        
        margin-top: 100px;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #fff;        
    }
</style>    

<header>
    бла-бла-бла...
</header>
<div class="layout">
    бла-бла-бла...
</div>
```